# Excel Dropdown Display Value in Adjacent Column

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown, vlookup

The code works for column 3 however when I add the extra line for column 10 it doesn't. I'd like to be able to run this for several different columns on the same worksheet. Thanks.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
selectedNa = Target.Value
If Target.Column = 3 Then
    selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, Worksheets("Risk Dropdowns").Range("B3:C30"), 2, False)

If Target.Column = 10 Then
    selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, Worksheets("Risk Dropdowns").Range("E3:F30"), 2, False)

        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            Target.Value = selectedNum
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `End If`s are in the wrong place. If you fix the [indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation), you'd be able to see the logical flow better. In any case, `Select Case` might be better here.

Answer (score 0):

The nested IF logic is not correct.  Currently if the column number is anything but 3 it exits the if and the 10 is never tested.  Use ElseIf.  And pull the other check into its own if.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim selectedNA As Variant
    selectedNA = Target.Value

    On Error GoTo safeout
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim selectedNum As Variant
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNA, Worksheets("Risk Dropdowns").Range("B3:C30"), 2, False)
    ElseIf Target.Column = 10 Then
        selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNA, Worksheets("Risk Dropdowns").Range("E3:F30"), 2, False)
    End If
    If Not selectedNum Is Nothing Then
        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            Target.Value = selectedNum
        End If
    End If

safeout:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you should benefit from `Select Case` syntax

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'exit of more than one cell changed

    Dim selectedNA As Variant ' use a Variant to store a possible error

    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 3
            selectedNA = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Worksheets("Risk Dropdowns").Range("B3:C30"), 2, False)

        Case 10
            selectedNA = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Worksheets("Risk Dropdowns").Range("E3:F30"), 2, False)

        Case … ' add all cases you need
            selectedNA = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Worksheets("Risk Dropdowns").Range("...."), 2, False) 'adjust Range to current case

        Case Else
            Exit Sub

    End Select

    If Not IsError(selectedNA) Then ' if VLookup succesful
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'disable events not to call this sub recursively
        Target.Value = selectedNA
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' enable events back
    End If


End Sub
```